# Run dbus-daemon inside Docker container

Tags: docker, dbus, unix-socket

I am trying to create a Docker container with a custom D-Bus bus running inside.

I configured my Dockerfile as follow:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
COPY myCustomDbus.conf /etc/dbus-1/
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y dbus
RUN dbus-daemon --config-file=/etc/dbus-1/myCustomDbus.conf
```

After building, the socket is created but it is flagged [as "file", not as "socket"](https://www.linux.com/blog/file-types-linuxunix-explained-detail), and I can not use it as a bus...

```
-rwxrwxrwx  1 root root    0 Mar 20 07:25 myCustomDbus.sock
```

If I remove this file and run the `dbus-daemon` command again in a terminal, the socket is successfully created :

```
srwxrwxrwx  1 root root    0 Mar 20 07:35 myCustomDbus.sock
```

I am not sure if it is a D-Bus problem or a docker one.

Comment: Could you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of using the "RUN" command, you should use the "ENTRYPOINT" one to run a startup script.

The Dockerfile should look like that :

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
COPY myCustomDbus.conf /etc/dbus-1/
COPY run.sh /etc/init/
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y dbus
ENTRYPOINT ["/etc/init/run.sh"]
```

And run.sh :

```
#!/bin/bash
dbus-daemon --config-file=/etc/dbus-1/myCustomDbus.conf --print-address
```

Comment: where can I find `/etc/dbus-1/myCustomDbus.conf ` file?

Comment: See the manual. You can use `--system` with no config file path.

Answer (score 3):

You should use a startup script. The "run" command is executed only when the container is created and then stopped.

Answer (score 1):

my run.sh:

```
if ! pgrep -x "dbus-daemon" > /dev/null
then
    # export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=$(dbus-daemon --config-file=/usr/share/dbus-1/system.conf --print-address | cut -d, -f1)

    # or:
    dbus-daemon --config-file=/usr/share/dbus-1/system.conf
    # and put in Dockerfile:
    # ENV DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=/var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket"
else
    echo "dbus-daemon already running"
fi

if ! pgrep -x "/usr/lib/upower/upowerd" > /dev/null
then
    /usr/lib/upower/upowerd &
else
    echo "upowerd already running"
fi
```

then chrome runs with

--use-gl=swiftshader

without errors